# JSP Page not loading

Tags: jsp, tomcat, memory-leaks, load

I have created a basic login using JSP files in NetBeans, anyway when I call login.jsp via my form. It just has the spinning loading symbol on Chrome and says waiting for localhost... and Tomcat is telling me it will create a memory leak, I can't seem to find the problem? Here is a part of my code from login.jsp. Does anyone know what could causing the page to just load? It can't be a loop because I cannot see one. Any help is appreciated.

```
<% 
Connection connectionDB = null;
PreparedStatement psDB = null;
ResultSet rsDB = null;
String getUsername = request.getParameter("loginUsername");
String getPassword = request.getParameter("loginPassword");
String sql = "SELECT Username, Password FROM SKAWEB WHERE Username= '" + getUsername +       "' AND Password='" + getPassword + "'";
String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.driver";
String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:1527/SKAWEB";
String userDB = "emmron";
String passDB = "test";
out.println("testing123");
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
try { 
connectionDB = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, userDB, passDB);
psDB = connectionDB.prepareStatement(sql);
rsDB = psDB.executeQuery();
out.println("hello");
if(rsDB.next()){ 
    out.println("yay");
 }


} catch (Exception errorMessage) {
  errorMessage.printStackTrace();
  out.println("blah");

}






%>
```

Comment: post the error stack trace here.

Comment: @Pheonix it's not throwing an exception, Tomcat outputs this, Jun 01, 2013 10:19:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()